# Cassandra CAS INSERT timeouts for requests with milliseconds latency

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are load-testing our cassandra cluster (3 nodes, replication factor 3) and started to receive occasional *WriteTimeoutExceptions* for CAS insert operations on one table:

```
CREATE TABLE users.by_identity (
        account ascii,
        domain ascii,
        identity text
        PRIMARY KEY ((account, domain), identity)
    );
```

We are doing inserts with *IF NOT EXISTS* clause to this table. When increasing load to > 10 inserts/s for one partition, client requests start to "time out":

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency SERIAL (2 replica were required but only 1 acknowledged the write)
```

WriteType for timeouts is *CAS* and exceptions are thrown only for this table. Execution time is always < 10ms. Read/write timeouts are configured to > 1000 ms on cluster and only this table is hitting the problem.

Any ideas what might be the issue we are hitting and why are we getting timeouts for requests with milliseconds latency?

We are on Cassandra v3.0.8 and Datastax Java driver v3.1.0.

Comment: What is your cas_contention_timeout_in_ms set to?

Comment: cas_contention_timeout_in_ms is 1000 ms. This issue happens also if there is no contention and we write only unique entries with CAS into single partition.

Comment: Locks are per partition, so unique entries into the same partition all contend for the same lock is my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but you are probably hitting this bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9328

You can likely confirm by reducing concurrency so there's only ever 1 request at a time (if your requests are super fast you can probably still just do 10 fast requests per second one after the other just don't have any concurrent) and leaving your cluster setup (3 nodes, replication factor 3) or leaving your request rate at 10/s and changing your cluster setup to a single node.  If you do either you probably won't see any timeouts < 1000 ms and then changing back to concurrency 10 and 3 nodes with replication factor 3 and you will likely reproduce the timeouts that are too low for the timeout setting again.

Unfortunately the bug report doesn't provide any pseudo code how to workaround this problem other but does say you should check the state yourself to see if the write actually happened and retry based on that.  If your writes are idempotent maybe you just need to simply retry.

Unfortunately for my purposes our application was quite complicated and we were unable to workaround without a lot of other work so we are still living with this bug.  If this is ends up being the problem you are having, I'd be interested to see an example in pseudocode how you were able to workaround it as it might provide inspiration for others hitting this problem as well.